# Why is my <button> not covering all the text inside it?

Tags: html, css, button

Basically, the button border is not covering all the text inside it.
How do I get it to cover all the text?

I have bootstrap installed and using it for some other components. Is it possible that bootstrap is interfering with this or something?

I have tried padding like many sites suggest, but it's not working.

```
<a target="_blank" href="/SignUp">
   <button className="btn-design">Join BridgeBurma Today</button>
</a>
```

This is the css

```
.btn-design{
  background-color: orange;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[image: error image]

Comment: There's no `className` attribute in HTML, only in the DOM.

Comment: Also your code works fine for me, is there more CSS that is being applied to that button to limit its width? Have a look in the Developer tools in Chrome or Firefox by pressing F12.

Comment: ONE THING: I have bootstrap installed and I'm using it for some other components. Is it possible that bootstrap is interfering with this or something?

Comment: AND: I did try just class instead of className, but it's still not working.

Comment: Check that your button isn't in some kind of grid, its width is being limited by some CSS on its containing parent element

Comment: Oh it is in a grid. That must be the problem. May be I did something wrong there. I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname

Comment: @TemaniAfif Question is not tagged with react.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen react seems to be irrelevant to the question so the OP decided to not use it and he kept the code as it is. The screenshot shows that background, radius, color, etc are working fine so I am pretty sure it's a react code.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone shows you some CSS solutions but in my opinion the worst mistake with the code here is the nested `button` inside the `a` Tag. This doesn't make sense and should be avoided at all costs since they are for completely different, yet related functionality. Both trigger some action on click and combining them can lead to unpleasant side effects.

```
<a target="_blank" href="/SignUp">
   <span classe="btn-design">Join BridgeBurma Today</span>
</a>
```

This would be a semantic valid HTML Markup, maybe you don't need span for this:

```css
.btn-design{
  background-color: orange;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="/SignUp" class="btn-design">
     Join BridgeBurma Today
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `Name` in `className` and it'll work like charm, see below

```css
.btn-design{
  background-color: orange;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="/SignUp">
   <button class="btn-design">Join BridgeBurma Today</button>
</a>
```

Comment: he is using react: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname .. className is valid

Comment: I not see `reactjs` in tag and I also not using `reactjs`.

Comment: check the screenshot, the CSS is applying fine which confirm that his code is fine and the use of `className` is not wrong and is not the issue too.